# dynamically cast() values to string and unpivot in BigQuery

Tags: dynamic, casting, unpivot

I have tables (of different schema) that consist of numerous rows (millions) with a unique id and at least 100-200 columns of various data types (INT64, String, Datetime, Float...etc). I need to unpivot the columns to rows dynamically and display pertaining values (including null values) in the next column. I need this only for data related to a selected id.
Here is an example of what I need.

An idea of how tables look and final result:

I wrote this code but I am getting the following error:
"Query error: The datatype of column does not match with other datatypes in the IN clause. Expected STRING, Found INT64 at [4:74]"

code I wrote:

```
declare myup string;
set myup=(
select concat('(',string_agg(column_name,','),')'),
from (select distinct column_name from `abc-def- 
bigqueryghi.dataset_info.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` 
where table_name='table_1' 
and column_name not in ("id")
)
);
execute immediate format("""
select*from `abc-def-bigquery-ghi.dataset_info.table_1`
unpivot
(values for column_name in %s)""",myup);
```

It is not possible to explicitly cast each column by name into string since some tables have up to 200 columns.
Null values also need to be displayed in final result since this needs to then be visualized on Google Data Studio.
Any ideas on how to solve this is highly appreciated.